# Any suggesstions to locate the below elements in Selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, element, locate

Example `HTML` below. I want to locate the elements which contains the text *Person* Attributes and *Age*.

```
<div id="ext-gen210" class="x-tool x-tool-toggle"></div>
<span id="ext-gen214" class="x-panel-header-text">Person Attributes</span>
</div>
<div id="ext-comp-1071" class=" DDView ListView" style="height: auto;">
   <p class="dragItem "><i class="icon-Gen"></i>Age</p>
</div>
```

Note: I am looking for a solution without using `xpath` or `id` or `className` as they might change with every new release of my website.

I tried to locate them using

> 'name' --> By.name("Person Attributes") and By.name("Age") but both failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`By.name` would check for the **`name` attribute**. What you need is to check the **text** of an element using `By.xpath`:

```
By.xpath('//div[span/text() = "Person Attributes"]')
```

Or, you can also check that an `id` element *starts with* `ext-gen`:

```
By.xpath('//div[starts-with(@id, "ext-gen")]')
```

Comment: Can you also tell me, how to check the text using starts-with or any similar way?

Comment: @bpk sure, refer to the text as `text()` or `.`: `//div[starts-with(., "beginning")]`.